# constructing a DFA and a regular expression for a given regular language

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

This is the question 1.12 from Introduction to the Theory of Computation 3rd Edition by Michael Sipser. The questions says,

> Let $D=\{w\mid w$ contains an even number of $\texttt{a}$'s and an odd
>   number of $\texttt{b}$'s and does not contain the substring
>   $\texttt{ab}$}. Give a DFA with five states that recognizes $D$ and a
>   regular expression that generates $D$.

I was able to construct a [image: minimal DFA] by using the intersection operation on the three simpler parts of $D$. I think that the regular expression that would generate $D$ is `b(bb)*(aa)*` but I'm not sure about it.

Is my regular expression correct? If yes, then if I apply the subset construction algorithm on [image: this] diagram (eps denotes ε) and minimize the resultant DFA, I should get the minimal DFA that I constructed through intersection, right?

Comment: @RickDecker Ok. Is my ε-NFA correct? I'd like to think that it is but different books use different notations for representing Kleene Star and I just used the one that is used by Hopcroft & Ullman in their book.

Comment: Your DFA and regular expression are correct. For the rest, you should show that your DFA is minimal (it is). It appears that your NFA is correct, so if you convert that to a DFA and minimize it you should get your original DFA (though it would be tedious to do by hand). Don't worry about the fact that there different ways to do the NFA to DFA construction: either will work.

Comment: @sixpointzero Seems to me that your real question here is "Is the minimal DFA always the same, no matter how I get it?". (We don't do homework checking.)

Comment: @Raphael I wasn't sure whether my regex was correct or not and that was the primary question. Another issue that I'm facing is that I can't seem to get the same regex from my minimal DFA using Arden's Lemma as described in your answer (the answer that I get is just too long). I'm also unable to get the minimal DFA using the regex using subset construction.

Oh well, I'll try again. By the way, this isn't homework.

Comment: 1) Yes, FA->RegEx methods are notorious for creating ugly and wildly different expressions *that all are equivalent*. Also, minimizing regular expressions is hard so checking them for equivalence it not always feasible.  2) If you get different automata after minimization you made a mistake. Check your steps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this question using two possible routes.

The **1st route** involves constructing the DFA by using the intersection operation on the simpler parts of $D$, *i.e.*,

$\{$even number of $a$'s$\} \cap\{$odd number of $b$'s$\}\cap\{$does not contain the substring $ab\}$

After that, I was able to reduce the DFA into a RegEx using the *State Elimination Method* and *Arden's Lemma*. The regular expression can be achieved by using Arden's Lemma as follows.

$$1\to a2+b4$$

$$2\to a2+b2$$

$$3\to a5+b2+\varepsilon$$

$$4\to a5+b1+\varepsilon$$

$$5\to a3+b2$$

Note that $2\to a2+b2$ will resolve as $2\to \varnothing$ and not $2\to (a+b)^*$.

The **2nd route** involves "knowing" that the regular expression is $b(bb)^*(aa)^*$ by analyzing the language $D$. This RegEx can be converted to an ε-NFA. After that, we can convert [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDnxU.png) ε-NFA to get a DFA which when minimized would give us [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOPF4.png).